How to get SQLite error in PHP/Laravel when quoted column does not exist
Related to my previous question, I found out that due to an error I made, Laravel generates a wrong SQL query:
select * from "companies" where "companies"."id" = '9c54986f-8284-4da9-b826-c7a723de279b' and "companies"."deleted_at" is null and "company_id" = '9c54986f-8284-4da9-b826-c7a723de279b'

The problem here is that company_id does not exist in companies; however, the query does not generate an error when run, it just returns no result.
I suppose the problem here is that "company_id" is treated as a literal instead of a column reference; if I remove the quotes I get a proper error:
Error: in prepare, no such column: company_id (1)

I also get a proper error if I add the table prefix to the column name:
sqlite> select * from "companies" where "companies"."id" = '9c54986f-8284-4da9-b826-c7a723de279b' and "companies"."deleted_at" is null and "companies"."compa
ny_id" = '9c54986f-8284-4da9-b826-c7a723de279b';
Error: in prepare, no such column: companies.company_id (1)

Is there a way to solve this problem by acting on Laravel's or SQLite's configuration? I cannot alter how the queries are generated, as they are generated by the framework itself.
Also, I am NOT asking why this specific query behave as it does, that was already clear to me.
The fragment  and "company_id" = '9c54986f-8284-4da9-b826-c7a723de279b' is generated by a global scope implemented like this:
abstract readonly class UnlessAuthorizedScope implements Scope {
    public function __construct(
        private   string  $modelField,
        protected ?string $authorizingPermission,
        private   string  $userField,
    ) {}

    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model): void {
        if (Auth::hasUser()) {
            $user = Auth::user();

            if (
                !$this->authorizingPermission
                || !$user?->can($this->authorizingPermission)
            ) {
                $builder->where(
                    $this->modelField,
                    $user?->{$this->userField}
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

which is then implemented in:
readonly class CurrentCompanyScope extends UnlessAuthorizedScope {
    public function __construct(?string $authorizingPermission = null, ?string $modelField = null) {
        parent::__construct(
            $modelField ?? "company_id",
            $authorizingPermission,
            "company_id"
        );
    }
}

and finally used as:
class Company extends Model {
    protected static function booted(): void {
        parent::booted();
        static::addGlobalScope(new CurrentCompanyScope(
            CompanyPermission::ViewAll->value,
            // the error was here, instead of specifying "id", I kept the default "company_id" value
        ));
    }
}


the error was here ... so did you already fix the issue in your Laravel code?

Yes, in this specific case, but I would also like a way to make it so that it would throw an error to my face, instead of failing silently, should I make a similar mistake again.

FWIW, Laravel likely double quotes the columns in case you happen to be using a keyword as an identifier.  So if Laravel stopped doing this, while it would solve your problem, it might create other problems.

Yes, I guessed as much, but I would like to know if there is a solution to this problem without losing framework functionality ... I just had an idea I might try.

Note: I have rolled back your question, whose recent edit invalidated my answer.  Don't change your question to include my answer.

I have no idea what you're talking about, as I simply showed HOW the query was generated; also, your improper edit has made my own answer lose its context, so I'll restore it.

I have been able to fix this problem by modifying the implementation of my base global scope:
abstract readonly class UnlessAuthorizedScope implements Scope {
    public function __construct(
        private   string  $modelField,
        protected ?string $authorizingPermission,
        private   string  $userField,
    ) {}

    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model): void {
        if (Auth::hasUser()) {
            $user = Auth::user();

            if (
                !$this->authorizingPermission
                || !$user?->can($this->authorizingPermission)
            ) {
                $builder->where(
                    $model->getTable().".".$this->modelField, // changed here
                    $user?->{$this->userField}
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

by adding an explicit table prefix to the field name, it was kept in the query generated by the framework, which then became:
select * from "companies" where "companies"."id" = '9c54986f-8284-4da9-b826-c7a723de279b' and "companies"."deleted_at" is null and "companies"."compa
ny_id" = '9c54986f-8284-4da9-b826-c7a723de279b'

and this new query generated a proper exception, which was caught by the framework and displayed on the page.

What I think is happening here is that "company_id" is being interpreted as a string literal, rather than a column.  Keep in mind that SQLite accepts string literals as either singly or doubly quoted.  Apparently, SQLite's heuristic for interpreting doubly quoted strings is:

First check if the string can be mapped to some database identifier (such as a column)
That failing, then treat the string as a string literal

Here is your query again, formatted:
SELECT *
FROM "companies"
WHERE
    "companies"."id" = '9c54986f-8284-4da9-b826-c7a723de279b' AND
    "companies"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND
    "company_id" = '9c54986f-8284-4da9-b826-c7a723de279b';

As the company_id column does not exist, this query appears to be getting interpreted as:
SELECT *
FROM "companies"
WHERE
    "companies"."id" = '9c54986f-8284-4da9-b826-c7a723de279b' AND
    "companies"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND
    'company_id' = '9c54986f-8284-4da9-b826-c7a723de279b';

Of course, the string comparison in the last term of the WHERE clause will never be true, hence no records are being returned.
There is no need for your columns to be in double quotes, so don't use them, to avoid this sort of problem.

RE There is no need for your columns to be in double quotes, so don't use them, to avoid this sort of problem.: as said in my question, I cannot alter how the queries are generated, as they are generated by the framework itself.

@MatteoTassinari Then the framework makes little sense if it adds random columns to your WHERE clause.  More likely is that your Laravel code is referring to the company_id column in some way.

@MatteoTassinari Well, either way, your question would be a lot clearer if it contained the code that generated your query.

Note: This was the answer to the original question asked.  The user subsequently changed the question, incorporating my answer.

Can you please explain what do you mean by "incorporating my answer"? That is, I do not understand which parts of your answer I would have "incorporated"? Really, it is not rethorical, I would like to understand if/what I did wrong, and English is not my primary language, so that's my difficulty here.

@TimBiegeleisen I re-read your answer, and if you feel that I have "incorporated" the part where you say that What I think is happening here is that "company_id" is being interpreted as a string literal, rather than a column., I would like to point out that such deduction was already in my very first revision; other than that, the rest of your answer is in no way present in my question.

RE: Then the framework makes little sense if it adds random columns to your WHERE clause., I never stated it was "random", I know why that query fragment was there and I fixed the source of this specific error, which is not the core of the question.
